# How to post viewbag values to post methos using ajax jquery in mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am retrieving my list of values in `ViewBag` and I am displaying `ViewBag` values in adropdownlist, but I am unable to post the dropdownlist values in `HttpPost` action. If I am using button values are passing to `HttpPost` action, ajax jquery not passing values. Please help me

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#refresh").change(function (e) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("update", "Home")',    
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
</script>
```

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
  { 
    @Html.DropDownList("StateType", ViewBag.StateType as SelectList, new { @id = "refresh" })
  }
}
                                          
[HttpPost]  ///values are not passing here
public ActionResult update(FormCollection FC)
{
}
```

Comment: You're not passing any data in your ajax call. I'd suggest reading some tutorials on jQuery ajax.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should works:

First Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
// put data into Viewbag
ViewBag.StateType = methodThatReturnsSelectList();
return View();
}
```

Index.cshtml is used because View() has no parameter and the controller's name is Index.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        { 

  @Html.DropDownList("StateType", ViewBag.StateType as SelectList, new { @id = "refresh" })


        }
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#refresh").change(function (e) {
               $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("update", "Home")',
                    data: $( "#myselect" ).val();
                });

               e.preventDefault();
           });
       });
    </script>
```

This AJAX Call make a POST request to the controller HOME and action Update (second controller), and give the value of the myselect id, so in the controller you catch it:

```
[HTTPOST]
public ActionResult Update(string value)
{
// doing stuff
}
```

I think it will clarify how to do and it will helps you.